# Using at command in shell script for scheduling a command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to use the feature of "at" command to schedule the execution of any specific command at some user defined time. Wondering if its possible using "at" command. I am   hoping "at" could help me because I  do not have privileges to schedule a cron task.

Things I have tried :

```
user>touch testfile |at 03:00  
job 30 at 2014-12-31 03:00  
user>ls -lrt testfile  
-rw-rw-r--  1 user group 0 Dec 31 02:59 testfile  <-----file created with command execution  
user>  

user> touch testfile1 | at -f 03:01
Garbled time
user>ls -lrt testfile*
-rw-rw-r--  1 user group 0 Dec 31 02:59 testfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 user group 0 Dec 31 02:59 testfile1
```

Comment: When you do not have privileges for cron, than you shouldn't have for "at" either. Before making a solution with at, ask your sysop about the security policy: Will they revoke your rigths for "at" in the future?
I would prefer granted rights for cron, since that makes things clear for the sysop (otherwise you might write your own cron-process with sleeps...)

Comment: thanks for warning , I will get the sysop's view on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
echo "touch testfile" | at 03:00
```

You're running `touch testfile` immediately, and piping its output to `at`. The input to `at` should be the command you want to run, not the output of the command.

If you want to run multiple commands, use a here-doc:

```
at 03:00 <<EOF
touch testfile
touch testfile1
EOF
```

Comment: After setting your `at` command to run at a specified time, you can check what is scheduled to run in your queue using the `atq` command. This allows a small confirmation that the system at least intends to run your command.